# observe in 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData' cannot be applied to ' model MVVM ANDROID

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I am trying to apply the mvvm model in android studio with java following this tutorial: https://medium.com/student-technical-community-vit-vellore/mvvm-with-room-db-and-retrofit-64c62c002591. Unlike the example, I am trying to use observer in a fragment but doing so gives me an error when calling the methods of the observer and I get this error **'observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer<? super java.util. List<com.example.wuad.Room.Model.Debates>>)' in 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData' cannot be applied to '(Fragments.reviewDebates, anonymous io.reactivex.Observer<java.util.List<com. example.wuad.Room.Model.Discussions>>)'**
I think the idea is  that  Observes the LiveData<List> from the ViewModel
I leave my code in case you can tell me where the error is.

**Model:**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.ForeignKey;
import androidx.room.Index;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;
import androidx.room.Relation;

@Entity(
        tableName = "debate", foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(
                entity = Users.class,
                parentColumns = {"user_id"},
                childColumns = {"user_id_fk"},
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
}
)

public class Debates {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    public int id_debate;
    public String title_debate;
    public String text_debate;
    public String begin_date;
    public String end_date;
    public String private_date;
    public String owner_type;
    public int lenght_debate;
    public String state_debate;
    public int max_args;
    public String tag;
    public String privacity;
    public int position_max;
    public int counter_args_max;
    public String counter_args_type;
    public String favorite_subject;
    public String participation_type;
    public String image_summary_debate;
    public int user_id_fk;

    public Debates(String title_debate, String text_debate, String begin_date, String end_date, String owner_type,String state_debate,String tag,String privacity,String favorite_subject,String participation_type, String counter_args_type,String image_summary_debate, int lenght_debate,int position_max, int max_args, int counter_args_max , int user_id_fk) {
        this.title_debate = title_debate;
        this.text_debate = text_debate;
        this.begin_date = begin_date;
        this.end_date = end_date;
        this.private_date = privacity;
        this.owner_type = owner_type;
        this.lenght_debate = lenght_debate;
        this.state_debate = state_debate;
        this.max_args = max_args;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.privacity = privacity;
        this.position_max = position_max;
        this.counter_args_max = counter_args_max;
        this.counter_args_type = counter_args_type;
        this.favorite_subject = favorite_subject;
        this.participation_type = participation_type;
        this.image_summary_debate = image_summary_debate;
        this.user_id_fk = user_id_fk;
    }

    public int getId_debate() {
        return id_debate;
    }

    public void setId_debate(int id_debate) {
        this.id_debate = id_debate;
    }

    public String getTitle_debate() {
        return title_debate;
    }

    public void setTitle_debate(String title_debate) {
        this.title_debate = title_debate;
    }

    public String getText_debate() {
        return text_debate;
    }

    public void setText_debate(String text_debate) {
        this.text_debate = text_debate;
    }

    public String getBegin_date() {
        return begin_date;
    }

    public void setBegin_date(String begin_date) {
        this.begin_date = begin_date;
    }

    public String getEnd_date() {
        return end_date;
    }

    public void setEnd_date(String end_date) {
        this.end_date = end_date;
    }

    public String getPrivate_date() {
        return private_date;
    }

    public void setPrivate_date(String private_date) {
        this.private_date = private_date;
    }

    public String getOwner_type() {
        return owner_type;
    }

    public void setOwner_type(String owner_type) {
        this.owner_type = owner_type;
    }

    public int getLenght_debate() {
        return lenght_debate;
    }

    public void setLenght_debate(int lenght_debate) {
        this.lenght_debate = lenght_debate;
    }

    public String getState_debate() {
        return state_debate;
    }

    public void setState_debate(String state_debate) {
        this.state_debate = state_debate;
    }

    public int getMax_args() {
        return max_args;
    }

    public void setMax_args(int max_args) {
        this.max_args = max_args;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getPrivacity() {
        return privacity;
    }

    public void setPrivacity(String privacity) {
        this.privacity = privacity;
    }

    public int getPosition_max() {
        return position_max;
    }

    public void setPosition_max(int position_max) {
        this.position_max = position_max;
    }

    public int getCounter_args_max() {
        return counter_args_max;
    }

    public void setCounter_args_max(int counter_args_max) {
        this.counter_args_max = counter_args_max;
    }

    public String getCounter_args_type() {
        return counter_args_type;
    }

    public void setCounter_args_type(String counter_args_type) {
        this.counter_args_type = counter_args_type;
    }

    public String getFavorite_subject() {
        return favorite_subject;
    }

    public void setFavorite_subject(String favorite_subject) {
        this.favorite_subject = favorite_subject;
    }

    public String getParticipation_type() {
        return participation_type;
    }

    public void setParticipation_type(String participation_type) {
        this.participation_type = participation_type;
    }

    public String getImage_summary_debate() {
        return image_summary_debate;
    }

    public void setImage_summary_debate(String image_summary_debate) {
        this.image_summary_debate = image_summary_debate;
    }

    public int getUser_id_fk() {
        return user_id_fk;
    }

    public void setUser_id_fk(int user_id_fk) {
        this.user_id_fk = user_id_fk;
    }
}
```

**Dao**

```
public interface DaoDatabase {
   
    @Query("SELECT * FROM debate WHERE state_debate=:value" )
    LiveData<List<Debates>>showDebates(String value);
}
```

**viewModel**

```
public class viewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    //se usa un modelo de vista de android porque necesitamos una aplicacion de contexto
    //para llamar a la bd
    private Repository repository;
    public LiveData<List<Debates>> getAllDebates;



    public viewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        //dentro del constructor de la vista se inicializan las variables con datos y la bd
        super(application);
        repository = new Repository(application);
        getAllDebates = repository.showAllDebatesOpen();

    }
    public LiveData<List<Debates>> getAllDebatesOpen(){
        return repository.showAllDebatesOpen();
    }


    /*public boolean validateUserLogin(String name){
        boolean value = repository.validateUser(name);
        return value;
    }*/



}
```

**Repository**

```
public class Repository {
    //esto contiene instanci a base de datos
    public DaoDatabase daoDatabase;
    //estos contiene los datos

    public LiveData<List<Profiles>> getAllPofiles;
    public LiveData<List<Debates>> getAllDebates;
    public LiveData<List<Argument>> getAllArgument;
    private wuadDatabase wuad;


    public Repository(Application application) {
        wuad= wuadDatabase.getInstance(application);
        daoDatabase = wuad.daoDatabase();
        getAllDebates = daoDatabase.showDebates("Open");


    }
    public LiveData<List<Debates>> showAllDebatesOpen(){
        return getAllDebates;
    }
    public void insertUser(Users user){
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> daoDatabase.insertUser(user));
    }
    public void insertProfile(Profiles profile){
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> daoDatabase.insertProfile(profile));
    }
    public void insertDebate(Debates debate){
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> daoDatabase.insertDebate(debate));
    }
    public int verifyIfExistUser(String name) throws  Exception,InterruptedException{
        Callable<Integer> callable = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                int value = daoDatabase.validateUser(name);
                return value;
            }
        };
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<Integer> task = executorService.submit(callable);
        int response= task.get();
        return response;

    }

    public int getIdUserRoom(String name) throws  Exception,InterruptedException{
        Callable<Integer> callable = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                int value = daoDatabase.getId(name);
                return value;
            }
        };
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<Integer> task = executorService.submit(callable);
        int response= task.get();
        return response;

    }
    public int getNumberData() throws  Exception,InterruptedException{
        Callable<Integer> callable = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                int value = daoDatabase.getNumberRow();
                return value;
            }
        };
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<Integer> task = executorService.submit(callable);
        int response= task.get();
        return response;

    }

    public int getidDebate() throws  Exception,InterruptedException{
        Callable<Integer> callable = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                int value = daoDatabase.getNumberDebate();
                return value;
            }
        };
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<Integer> task = executorService.submit(callable);
        int response= task.get();
        return response;

    }
    public List<Users> getDataUserRoom (int id) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Callable<List<Users>> callable = new Callable<List<Users>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Users> call() throws Exception {
                List<Users> value = daoDatabase.getDataUsers(id);
                return value;
            }
        };
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<List<Users>> task = executorService.submit(callable);
        List<Users> response= task.get();
        return response;
    }
    public List<Profiles> getDataProfileRoom (int id) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Callable<List<Profiles>> callable = new Callable<List<Profiles>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Profiles> call() throws Exception {
                List<Profiles> value = daoDatabase.getDataProfiles(id);
                return value;
            }
        };
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<List<Profiles>> task = executorService.submit(callable);
        List<Profiles> response= task.get();
        return response;
    }
    

}
```

**Fragment**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(viewModel.class);
        LiveData<List<Debates>> test = model.getAllDebatesOpen();
        model.getAllDebatesOpen().observe(this, new Observer<List<Debates>>() {


            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Debates> debates) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
    }
```

regards !